# Each element is sharing the same state and not its own

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to React and I am trying to create a simple voting app which has a list of items, each with a number of votes and a button to increment the votes for that particular item.

The issue I am having is that the votes are being updated for all items at once and not for that particular item. It seems that each item successfully has its own unique key, but I am not understanding why I am not able to single out that particular one to increment its votes.

I have tried creating a separate function in order to run this.props.items.map() but I had no luck with that either.

My code so far:

```
    <script src="node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        class List extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    votes: 0,
                }
                this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            }

        handleClick(event) {
            const votes = this.state.votes;
            this.setState({
                votes: votes + 1
            })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Vote Your JS Library!</h1>
                    <ul>
                        { this.props.items.map((item) => 
                            <li key = {item}>
                                {this.state.votes}
                                {item}
                                <button onClick = { () => this.handleClick() }> + </button>
                            </li>
                        ) }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<List items= { ['React', 'Vue', 'Angular', 'Ember'] } />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot this `data-plugins="transform-class-properties"` in `<script type="text/babel">`

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke Thank you! I have added it to the script tag. My issue still remains, unfortunately.

Comment: You have the issue because you have only one `votes` object and you render it in your `map` loop. Since you need every `item` to have its own vote counter you should add and extra `votes` property to the `item` structure.

Comment: try to create `ListItem` component which will have it's own `votes` state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a single votes variable and rendering it for all the items so that is why you are getting the same thing for all the items so try doing this way:

working example https://codesandbox.io/s/7ym8606pm0:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      votes: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    }
    this.items = [];
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const newVotes = [...this.state.votes];
    newVotes[i] = newVotes[i] + 1;
    this.setState({
      votes: newVotes
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Vote Your JS Library!</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
            <li key={item}>
              {this.state.votes[index]}
              {item}
              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}> + </button>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List items={['React', 'Vue', 'Angular', 'Ember']} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each list item will needs it own state,

```
this.state = {
                reactVotes: 0,
                vueVotes: 0,
                angularVotes: 0,
                emberVotes: 0,
            }
```

For the sake of simplicity create an event handler for each list item. Once you have that working you could apply the principle of DRY (do not repeat yourself), if you see the opportunity. Otherwise leave it for a later date, after all you're just getting started with React.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<script type="text/babel">
      class List extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                  items: this.props.items,
              }
              this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
          }

      handleClick(itemName) {
          const givenItemSet = this.state.items.slice();
          var newItemList = givenItemSet.map(el => {
                      if(el.name === itemName)
                         return Object.assign({}, el, {votes: el.votes + 1})
                      return el
                  });

          this.setState({
            items: newItemList
          })
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                  <h1>Vote Your JS Library!</h1>
                  <ul>
                      { this.state.items.map((item) => 
                          <li key = {item.name}>
                              {item.votes}
                              {item.name}
                              <button onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(this, item.name)}> + </button>
                          </li>
                      ) }
                  </ul>
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

    const listItems = [{
      name: 'React',
      votes: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Vue',
      votes: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Angular',
      votes: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Ember',
      votes: 0
    }]

    ReactDOM.render(<List items= { listItems } />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your votes state is for List component & not for each ListItem.

You can solve it by either creating a new Component called ListItem which will receive name as props and in this component you can define votes state that will be for each item. Also move handleClick function in this component.

```
`class ListItem extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       votes: 0,
     }
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   handleClick(event) {
     const votes = this.state.votes;
     this.setState({
       votes: votes + 1
     })
   }
   render() {
     return <li>
       {this.state.votes}
       {item}
       <button onClick = { () => this.handleClick() }> + </button>
     </li>
   }
}
```

`

or you can manage hash of states in your current list component like this.

```
class List extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                votes: {},
            }
            this.items = [];
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        }

    handleClick(item) {
        const votes = this.state.votes;
        votes[item] = (votes[item] || 0) + 1;
        this.setState({
            votes: votes
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Vote Your JS Library!</h1>
                <ul>
                    { this.props.items.map((item) => 
                        <li key = {item}>
                            {this.state.votes[item] || 0}
                            {item}
                            <button onClick = { () => this.handleClick(item) }> + </button>
                        </li>
                    ) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the `this.state.votes` for each item.Its for all.

Need a change in data structure.

```
<List  items = {

'React' : { votes: 0},
'Vue'  :  { votes: 0},
'Angular'  : { votes: 0},
'Ember'  : { votes: 0}
} />
```

**constructor :**

```
constructor(props) {
    ....
    this.state.items = this.props.items;
    ...
}
```

**render:**

```
<ul>
  {this
    .state
    .items
    .map((item,name) => <li key={name}>
      {item.votes}
      {name}
      <button onClick= { () => this.handleClick(name) }>
        +
      </button>
    </li>)}
</ul>
```

**handleClick**

```
handleClick=(name)=> {

    let  updatedItems = { [name] : parseInt(this.state.items[key].votes) + 1 };

    this.setState({
        item: [...this.state.items,...updatedItems]
    })
}
```